# MS Access Like query from a combo box

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am attempting to generate a report from MS access 2013 that is created based on a selection from a combo box. My setup:

Table: Employee contact information with the last column being "EmployeeSkills" with skills listed in one cell separated by commas (i.e. "programming, design, excel, strategy"

Forms: I created a form with a combo box listing possible skills an employee could have. A user selects the skill ("i.e." programming" and clicks the button to generate the report.

Query: My query searches the criteria of the combo box by [Forms]![CreateReport]![cmbSkills]

I know that I need some type of a "Like" function since my skills are grouped together and I am not looking for an exact match. Is there a function of some sort that I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you need the `LIKE` operator. What you are probably missing, are the wildcard characters.

Therefore what you need is to modify your query's `WHERE` clause to the following:

```
Where [EmployeeSkills] Like "*" & [Forms]![CreateReport]![cmbSkills] & "*"
```

Try it out :)

Comment: Access is forcing quotes around the where clause like this:"Where [EmployeeSkills]" Like "*" & [Forms]![CreateReport]![cmbSkills] & "*" is that correct?

Comment: Try pasting the statement above in the sql editor of the query, not the graphic one. I believe for the graphic one you would need only `Like "*" & [Forms]![CreateReport]![cmbSkills] & "*"` on the EmployeeSkills column